# How to use a custom breakpoint function without having to return to the place breakpoint was called

Tags: python, pdb

I am running an interactive ssh python program, but I'm not always technically interacting with it (piping stdout and stdin). I need to print a string to signal to pexpect on my local machine that a breakpoint has been called and to enter interactive mode.

On my local machine I have:

```py
p: pexpect.spawn
i = p.expect([pexpect.EOF,'__INTERACT__'])
if i==1:
    p.interact()
```

The reason I do this is because I cannot simply `interact()` the whole time it is running. This interferes with stdout on the local process.

So on the remote process, I breakpoint with

```py
print('__INTERACT__')
breakpoint()
```

This works, however I want to have single-line breakpoints. So I tried:

```
def remote_breakpoint():
    print('__INTERACT__')
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
sys.breakpointhook = remote_breakpoint
```

This allows me to just write `breakpoint()`. It's also allows me to disable the extra print statement when running locally:

```py
def remote_breakpoint():
    if platform.system() != 'Darwin':
        print('__INTERACT__')
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

It works, But now pdb starts inside the `remote_breakpoint` function and I have to hit `r` to get out every time. How can I tell `pdb.set_trace` to start one function up the stack, or make it wait to start the interactive process until `remote_breakpoint` has returned?

Even if I just call `remote_breakpoint()` (instead of using sys.breakpointhook), I still have the same problem.